# WSO2 DSS : maximum length SQL statement / compound SQL statement (SQL Server)

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have created a compound SQL statement as a query for a dataservice. It works when the statement is +/- 600 characters long.

When I add more functionality to the SQL statement, after saving the SQL statement the full service becomes invalid (statement is +/- 3500 characters)

Is there a maximum length on the SQL statement that can be added in a dataservice ?

Kind regards

Tore